# undefined method `to' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper: (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a rails 5.2 app with the following in config/routes.rb

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

Upon running rails s, I get the following error :

> undefined method `to' for #

Comment: Is that all you have in `routes.rb` ? Can you replace it with `root 'home#index'` ?

Comment: This cannot be reproduced. The error is most likely due to malformed syntax somewhere else in `routes.rb`.

Comment: That's my guess as well. Could you share your `routes.rb`. Make sure, you're `quotes` and `double quotes` look like `'` and `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the shortcut?

```
root 'home#index'
```

And did you already use get to map the request?

```
get 'home/index'
```

Comment: `root 'home#index'` is just a shorthand for `root to: 'home#index'`. And providing a `get 'home/index'` route is completely unnecessary since the former mounts a route at `/`. The latter just adds a junk route.